# VSCode SSH remote, Jupyter notebook couldn't run

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, jupyter, remote-server

I want to use a linux computer as my remote server,but I don't know linux at all. Now I can connect to the server by VSCode, but the Jupyter notebook couldn't run, which shows the error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.10.1101450599/pythonFiles/vscode_datascience_helpers/daemon/daemon_python.py", line 54, in _decorator
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.10.1101450599/pythonFiles/vscode_datascience_helpers/jupyter_daemon.py", line 108, in m_exec_module_observable
    self._start_notebook(args, cwd, env)
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.10.1101450599/pythonFiles/vscode_datascience_helpers/jupyter_daemon.py", line 162, in _start_notebook
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 264, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2292, in start
    self.exit(1)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 836, in exit
    sys.exit(exit_status)
SystemExit: 1

[C 09:18:09.652 NotebookApp] 不建议以root身份运行.使用--allow-root绕过过.

Failed to run jupyter as observable with args notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir="/root/xuzelin" --config=/tmp/05f04b57-2d6d-4311-a101-40d551d1e24b/jupyter_notebook_config.py --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000.0
```

How could I fix this Error?

Answer (score 2):

Currently we don't support connecting as a root user to a remote notebook. Best solution here would be to connect as a non-root user. We can consider adding a way to pass --allow-root flag, but we don't currently support this.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/739

Comment: But how to connect as a non-root user? Please forgive me, I'm fresh

Answer (score 0):

run this command to run a jupyter server manually:

> jupyter notebook --allow-root --no-browser --notebook-dir=some_dir

and you got a link of your server like this:

> http://ip:8888/?token=xxxx

then click the kernel button, and choose "connect to another jupyter server", fill in the jupyter link, it works!